# Ending I/O context in linux block device drivers

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, block, device

I'm writing a Linux block device driver for some custom hardware.

I've gone back and forth whether to the *make_request()* interface or the *request_fn()* interface and in either case I cannot find a clear answer as to whether or not the requested data needs to be resolved in the thread context where the data was requested.

For instance, some data is requested of my driver by the kernel, by which my make_request() callback is invoked. Am I *required* to deliver that data (e.g. using bio_endio() ) before I return from that callback, or could I perhaps call that bio_endio() in a different thread/task (e.g. if I was waiting on an IRQ from a DMA to tell me that data is locally available, I could return in the BH.)

In my testing, if I *don't* call bio_endio() before the end of the callback's scope, the kernel and the calling process hang, as would be expected--but they eventually panic... which would lead me to believe that either a) the panic is more to warn the driver developer that he should have returned *SOMETHING* within a "reasonable" amount of time (irrespective of the thread context) or that I shouldn't have returned at all without providing either the data or an error code.

Answer (score 0):

Try read "The Art of Linux Kernel Design 2014" Page: 58; - item "Initialize the Request Structure of the I Block Device.

att

Comment: The "0.11" revision of the kernel which that book references is useless; the block layer has changed even since the targeted version of the unreleased LDD3.